# Pandas MultiIndex DataFrame.rolling offset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate, multi-index

**Why can't I use an offset when `rolling` a multi-index DataFrame?**  For example, with:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-01-03', periods=20, freq='8D')
i = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A','B','C'], rng], names=['Name','Date'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(60), i, columns=['Vals'])
```

If I try grouping and rolling with an offset I get "**ValueError: window must be an integer**":

```
df['Avg'] = df.groupby(['Name'])['Vals'].rolling('30D').mean() # << Why doesn't this work?
```

Not that these following variants meet my needs, but note that grouping and rolling with an `int` works:

```
df['Avg'] = df.groupby(['Name'])['Vals'].rolling(4).mean()
```

And I can roll with an offset on a single-index subset of the DataFrame:

```
d = df.loc['A']
d['Avg'] = d['Vals'].rolling('30D').mean()
```

If it's truly impossible to do rolling with offsets on multi-index DataFrames, what would be the most efficient workaround to apply one to each level-0 index item?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to use an offset like '30D' you need a simple date index.  In this case the simplest way to achieve that is to move 'Name' out of the index with `reset_index(level='Name')`, leaving you with only 'Date' as the index:

```
df['Avg'] = df.reset_index(level='Name').groupby(['Name'])['Vals'].rolling('30D').mean()
```

Answer (score 1):

Rolling support over one level of a MultiIndex is still imperfect, see: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/34642

Alternatively to @JohnE's solution, one can use the [transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.transform.html#) method:

```
df.groupby(level='Name')\
  .Vals\
  .transform(lambda d: d.rolling('30D', on=d.index.levels[1])\
                        .mean()
            )
```

Notice that the code without `transform`:

```
df.groupby(level='Name')\
  .Vals\
  .rolling('30D', on=df.index.levels[1])\
  .mean()
```

throws an `IndexError` (at least on Pandas 1.5).