# Search for regex within dict considering TimeInterval dict's key

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I have the following data structure - list of dicts. Each dict contains: {ip:x.x.x.x, timestamp: , message: "yyyyy"}:

```
list1 =[
{'ip': '11.22.33.44', 'timestamp': 1665480231699, 'message': '{"body": "Idle time larger than time period. retry:0"}', 'ingestionTime': 1665480263198},
{'ip': '11.22.33.42', 'timestamp': 1665480231698, 'message': '{"body": "Idle time larger than time period. retry:5"}', 'ingestionTime': 1665480263198}, 
{'ip': '11.22.33.44', 'timestamp': 1665480231698, 'message': '{"body": "Idle time larger than time period. retry:0"}', 'ingestionTime': 1665480263198}
]
```

In addition i have a regexes list (whitelist_metadata) that i want to search (MetricMsg) in above dicts msg, and check (according timestamp) if it appear X times within time intervals (for our example 1 min) - the verification should be per single ip.

```
whitelist_metadata = [
  {
    'LogLevel': 'WARNING',
    'SpecificVersion': 'None',
    'TimeInterval(Min)': 1,
    'MetricMsg': 'DDR: XXXX count got lost',
    'AllowedOccurrenceInTimeInterval': 0   --> this means that we are allowing this msg always 
  },
  {
    'LogLevel': 'WARNING',
    'SpecificVersion': 'None',
    'TimeInterval(Min)': 1,
    'MetricMsg': 'Idle time larger than XXX time. retry: \\d ',     --> please notice it's a regex 
    'AllowedOccurrenceInTimeInterval': 5  --> this means that are allowing this msg only if happened not more than 5 times within 1min.
  }
]
```

My native thought was to :

1. Run on each ip's message value searching for single regex match (will run in a loop since we have multiple regexes to search for).
2. Once msg found - save its timestamp and check diff between previous timestamps ... (guess there are pandas tricks to support time interval check better, saw this that i haven't used yet : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-group-data-by-time-intervals-in-python-pandas/ )

   - if it's within allowed TimeInterval and <= AllowedOccurrenceInTimeInterval  - pop it from all server ip timestamps msg list.
   - else - leave it in the msg list

i started to code it like this :

```
 import pandas as pd
 df = pd.DataFrame(list1)
 df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], unit="ms")
 group_per_ip = df.sort_values('timestamp').groupby("ip")
 # for ip in group_per_ip.groups.keys():
 #   single_ip = group_per_ip.get_group(ip)
 single_ip  =  group_per_ip.get_group('11.22.33.44')
```

now i trying to figure our how to run pandas rolling("5m") function on it but it keep throwing the same error:
`ValueError('window must be an integer',)`

i tried to follow : [Python, Pandas ; ValueError('window must be an integer',)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50569205/python-pandas-valueerrorwindow-must-be-an-integer) but it didn't help

could someone help me find a way to implement it using pandas or other good performance suggestion that deals with such TimeInterval issue?

Answer (score 0):

sharing the rod and i continued from there..

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import json

list1 = [
    {'ip': '11.22.33.44', 'timestamp': 1665480231699,
        'message': '{"body": "Idle time larger than time period. retry:0"}', 'ingestionTime': 1665480263198},
    {'ip': '11.22.33.42', 'timestamp': 1665480231698,
        'message': '{"body": "Idle time larger than time period. retry:5"}', 'ingestionTime': 1665480263198},
    {'ip': '11.22.33.44', 'timestamp': 1665480231698,
        'message': '{"body": "Idle time larger than time period. retry:0"}', 'ingestionTime': 1665480263198}
]

df = pd.DataFrame(list1)
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], unit="ms")
group_per_ip = df.sort_values('timestamp').groupby("ip")
# for ip in group_per_ip.groups.keys():
#   single_ip = group_per_ip.get_group(ip)
single_ip = group_per_ip.get_group('22.132.44.253')

# %%
single_ip_index = single_ip.set_index('timestamp')
single_ip_temp = single_ip_index['message'].apply(func=lambda x: re.match(
    r"Idle time larger than time period. retry:\d+", json.loads(x)['body']) is not None)
single_ip_temp.rolling('2T').count() > 1.5
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).